# Ruby: Multi-line conditional syntax: how do I do it?

Tags: ruby, syntax

What I'm trying to do:

```
result = (not question?) \
          and ( \
            condition \
            or ( \
              comparer == compared and another_question? \ 
            ) \
          )
```

The goal is to have complicated and / or logic and still have it be readable.

The problem with the above attempted syntax is that it some how messes up parenthesis in ruby's parser, so console says that the error is in a file that this code isn't in. (though it's in the call stack)

without the back slashes, I get these:

```
syntax error, unexpected kAND, expecting kEND (SyntaxError)
```

and

```
 syntax error, unexpected kOR, expecting ')'
```

any ideas on how to properly do this?

Comment: In the sample, there's a space after `another_question? \ `. Does the space exist in the original code?

Comment: Very much so. "\" escapes the following character.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Remove the space after the backslash in `another_question? \`. You're escaping the space rather than the newline, which causes a syntax error.

Note you don't need to escape every newline.

```
result = (not question?) \
          and (
            condition \
            or (
              comparer == compared and another_question?
            )
          )
```

Answer (score 13):

For logical expression, you should use `&&`, `||`, `!`, not `and`, `or`, `not`.

`and`, `or`, `not` should only be used for control-flow.

One reason is that `&&`, `||`, `!` have higher precedence than `and`, `or`, `not`.

Read more about this in [this blog post](http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/).

Answer (score 8):

Make sure each line (except the last) ends with an operator so the interpreter "knows" there will be more operands coming, e.g.

```
result = (not question?) and (
                condition or
                (comparer == compared and another_question?)
         )
```

(tested with MRI 1.8.7)

Comment: is there no way to have the operators on a new line?

Comment: @TheLindyHop: Yes, masking the line-breaks with backslash ;-) I don't know of other possibilities. Maybe you could rework the code to avoid overly complex logical expressions?

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
sub = (comparer == compared and another_question?)
result = (not question?) and (condition or sub)
```

No need to make the whole thing one expression.

Comment: I tend to break lengthy boolean expressions down into methods that name (and delegate to) the aspects of the expression, assigning readable names that express what is being tested.

Comment: @d11wtq One line methods are not readable either! Imagine going back into your code and seeing dozens of methods in an if statement, and having to trace down each method to find out what it does. Methods should only be extracted if they will be used in multiple locations.